# Где можно найти список распространённых существительных в текстовом формате?

Tags: текст, работа-с-текстом

Нужен список от 500 до пару тысяч, для игры. Всё что находил - списки от 100 тысяч и выше. А как из такого списка убрать редко используемые слова - не знаю.

Comment: Ну вот 1000 штук с частотой http://dict.ruslang.ru/freq.php?act=show&dic=freq_s&title=%D7%E0%F1%F2%EE%F2%ED%FB%E9%20%F1%EF%E8%F1%EE%EA%20%E8%EC%E5%ED%20%F1%F3%F9%E5%F1%F2%E2%E8%F2%E5%EB%FC%ED%FB%F5

Comment: спасибо. Напишу парсер чтобы их достать, так как там скачать нельзя, а в других местах не нашёл.

Comment: wordle что ли делаешь?)

Comment: Qwertiy да) оказывается это известная игра, пока делал не знал об этом.